# iPhone: To develop log module persistently and use for upload

Tags: iphone

Is there a log sample developed in any of the iPhone project? I am developing an iPhone application and we want to have logging string stored line by line basis persistently somewhere and use it for upload to our server etc. it should keep logging behind the scene when my application does syncing under thread etc. I don't know how to develop this efficiently. Could someone please share me link or samples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger)

NSLogger is a high perfomance logging utility which displays traces emitted by client applications running on Mac OS X or iOS (iPhone OS). It replaces your usual NSLog()-based traces and provides powerful additions like display filtering, image and binary logging, traces buffering, timing information, etc.

NSLogger feature summary:

- View logs using the Mac OS X desktop viewer, accept connections from
  local network clients (using Bonjour) or remote clients connecting
  directly over the internet
- Online (application running and connected to NSLogger) and offline
  (saved logs) log viewing
- Buffer all traces in memory or in a file, send them over to viewer
  when a connection is acquired
- Secure logging (connections use SSL by default)
- Advanced log filtering options
- Save viewer logs to share them and/or review them later
- Export logs to text files
- Open raw buffered traces files that you brought back from client
  applications not directly connected to the log viewer